# How to convert hex data to decimal degree latitude and longitude?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, gps-time

I have been trying to decode GPS coordinates (latitude and longitude) which is in HEX format, and the documentation doesn't have a clear explanation, please help me out. I'm adding some examples below.

latitude    0x414F51 = +28.758963 dd(decimal degree)

longitude   0x45429B = +077.627784dd(decimal degree)

[screenshot of the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjq0H.png)

[official documentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LyrjN76F-_us1IhmssmuZg-9ufj-GmUV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation instead of just a screenshot of some portion of it?

Comment: @Abion47 you can find the full doc here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LyrjN76F-_us1IhmssmuZg-9ufj-GmUV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The document doesn't explain anything, yeah. Plugging in those hex values and their binary equivalents doesn't produce decimal values in any popular floating point representations that are anywhere near what they are supposed to be, nor do they appear to be a fixed point representation either. You might want to try taking this over to [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or maybe [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) to see if maybe they can crack the bit format.

Comment: @Abion47 Thanks for your suggestion, we got it solved here https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/20575/27377